# Integrating $\int_{-L}^L e^{i\pi k x/L} \cosh(x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, trigonometry

> **Question:**
>   Integrate $$\int_{-L}^L \exp({i\pi k x/L}) \cosh(x)\,dx$$

My attempt:

$$=\frac{1}{2} \int_{-L}^L e^{x(1+\pi ki/L)}+e^{-x(1-\pi ki/L)}\,dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{e^{x(1+\pi ik/L)}}{(1+\pi ik/L)}-\frac{e^{-x(1-\pi ik/L)}}{(1-\pi ik/L)}\right]_{x=-L}^L$$

$$=\frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{e^{x(1+\pi ik/L)}(1-\pi ik/L)-e^{-x(1-\pi ik/L)}(1+\pi ik/L)}{(1+\pi ik/L)(1-\pi ik/L)}\right]_{x=-L}^L$$

$$=\frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{e^{x(1+\pi ik/L)}-\frac{\pi ik}{L} e^{x(1+\pi ik/L)}-e^{-x(1-\pi ik/L)}- \frac{\pi ik}{L} e^{-x(1-\pi ik/L)}}{1+\frac{\pi ^2k^2}{L^2}}\right]_{x=-L}^L$$

$$=\left[\frac{e^{\pi ikx/L}\sinh(x)-\frac{\pi ik}{L}e^{\pi ikx/L}\cosh(x)}{1+\frac{\pi ^2k^2}{L^2}}\right]_{x=-L}^L$$

$$=\frac{e^{\pi ik}\sinh(L)-\frac{\pi ik}{L}e^{\pi ik}\cosh(L)+e^{-\pi ik}\sinh(L)+\frac{\pi ik}{L}e^{-\pi ik}\cosh(L)}{1+\frac{\pi ^2k^2}{L^2}}$$

$$=\frac{2\sinh(L)\cosh(\pi ik)+2\frac{\pi ik}{L}\cosh(L)\sinh(\pi ik)}{1+\frac{\pi ^2k^2}{L^2}}$$

The answer says:
$$\frac{(-1)^k}{2} \left(\frac{e^L-e^{-L}}{1+\pi ik/L}+\frac{e^L-e^{-L}}{1-\pi ik/L}\right)$$

$$=(-1)^k \frac{L\sinh(L)}{L^2+\pi^2k^2}$$

I just don't see it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: As your question is right now, it is pretty hard to read. Please don't use $*$ as a multiplication-sign - simply leave it out. Also, use a backslash in front of all known functions, such as \sin, \cosh, etc. to make them look nicer. And finally, use the \align environment for the equations, see here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5024/259085

Comment: I've edited your question, please check if everything is on the right place ;)

Comment: @kamil09875, somehow my edit overwrote yours. could you please redo the editing? (I am not very familiar with the align yet) Thanks,

Comment: It seems to me that the result should be $\frac{2 (-1)^k L^2 \sinh (L)}{\pi ^2 k^2+L^2}$.Also remember that $\sinh(ix)=i\sin(x)$ and $\cosh(ix)=\cos(x)$.

Comment: you could have put limit in second step and directly got the answer @jie li

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Thanks so much!!! The identity you provided solves the problem which bothered me for nearly 2 days! I will list it as answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$=\frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{e^{x(1+\pi ik/L)}}{(1+\pi ik/L)}-\frac{e^{-x(1-\pi ik/L)}}{(1-\pi ik/L)}\right]_{x=-L}^L=$$

$$=\frac{L}{2} \left[\frac{e^{\pi ik} (e^L-e^{-L})+e^{-\pi ik}(e^L-e^{-L})}{(L^2+\pi^2 k^2)} \right]$$

and $$e^{\pi ik}=e^{-\pi ik}=(-1)^k$$

Comment: Right, from here is much simpler